# ASP.NET MVC - Write less code for route template

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my code:

```
routes.MapRouteLowercase(
                name: "productadd",
                url: "product/add",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Product",
                    action = "Add"
                }
                    , namespaces: new[] { "project.Controllers" });
            routes.MapRouteLowercase(
                name: "productlike",
                url: "product/like",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Product",
                    action = "Like"
                }
                    , namespaces: new[] { "project.Controllers" });
            routes.MapRouteLowercase(
                name: "productshow",
                url: "product/{id}/{seoName}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Product",
                    action = "Get",
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    seoName = UrlParameter.Optional
                }
                    , namespaces: new[] { "project.Controllers" });
```

I want a solution for writing less codes, actually a template for productshow and another template for product actions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [Attribute Based Routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) in MVC.  This is available by default in MVC5, or can be installed as a NuGet package in MVC4.

With Attribute Based Routing, you can define Attributes on your action methods, rather than magic string matches in the routing table.  You can also perform more advanced type checking, such as minimum and maximum values, and optionally name routes for easy reference in your Razor.

as an example:

```
[RoutePrefix("product")]
public class ProductController : Controller {

//route /product
[Route] 
public ActionResult Index() { ... } 

//route /product/add
[Route("add")]
public ActionResult Add() { ... }

//route /product/like
// <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("productLike")">Like</a>
[Route("like", Name="productlike")]
public ActionResult Like() { ... }

//route /product/{id}/{seoName}
[Route("{id?}/{seoName?}")]
public ActionResult Get(int? id, string seoName) { ... }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Saman, you can create a default route, like this one below. I'm not sure if that will work with "MapRouteLowercase", you can give it a try.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { 
                controller = "Home", 
                action = "Index", 
                id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC) has more options if you want.

Comment: Thiago my friend tanx, but it work just for actions not "/product/{id}/{seoName}"